# Alter table adding column having error

Tags: mysql, alter

I'm adding a new column in a table, and while doing the alteration I received an error.

Please see below:

`ALTER TABLE dbname.table_name ADD COLUMN column_name TINYINT(1) UNSIGNED DEFAULT 0;
ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry '300866' for key 'PRIMARY'`

```
mysql> show create table dbname.table_name\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: table_name
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `table_name` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `sku` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `status` enum('active','inactive','deleted') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'active',
  `status_supplier_config` enum('active','inactive','deleted') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'active',
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `description` text COMMENT 'Description of the product',
  `fk_catalog_brand` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `primary_category` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `fk_catalog_import` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `display_if_out_of_stock` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `fk_catalog_config_group` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `fk_catalog_attribute_set` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `pet_status` set('creation','edited','images') DEFAULT NULL,
  `pet_approved` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `created_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_by_config` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `updated_by_config` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `activated_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `supplier_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sku_supplier_config` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'SKU of product at supplier',
  `creation_source_config` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `product_line` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Product Line/Range/Sub-Brand',
  `model` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Model ID of Manufacturer part number',
  `fk_catalog_attribute_option_global_supplier_type` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Type of supplier',
  `fk_catalog_attribute_option_global_season` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Season',
  `fk_catalog_attribute_option_global_gender` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Gender',
  `fk_catalog_attribute_option_global_production_country` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Production country of product',
  `imported` tinyint(1) unsigned DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Is the product imported from outside Australia?',
  `note` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Note / comment',
  `source_url_1` text COMMENT 'Product URL (scraped products)',
  `source_cost_1` decimal(11,2) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Cost Supplier 1 (Gross)',
  `source_ship_cost_1` decimal(11,2) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Ship Cost Supplier 1 (Gross)',
  `source_ship_time_1` int(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Averate Lead Shipping Time by Supplier',
  `fk_catalog_attribute_option_global_source_stock_1` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Stock Supplier 1',
  `source_url_2` text COMMENT 'Product URL (scraped products)',
  `source_cost_2` decimal(11,2) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Cost Supplier 2 (Gross)',
  `source_ship_cost_2` decimal(11,2) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Ship Cost Supplier 2 (Gross)',
  `source_ship_time_2` int(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Averate Lead Shipping Time by Supplier',
  `fk_catalog_attribute_option_global_source_stock_2` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Stock Supplier 2',
  `source_url_3` text COMMENT 'Product URL (scraped products)',
  `source_cost_3` decimal(11,2) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Cost Supplier 3 (Gross)',
  `source_ship_cost_3` decimal(11,2) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Ship Cost Supplier 3 (Gross)',
  `source_ship_time_3` int(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Averate Lead Shipping Time by Supplier',
  `fk_catalog_attribute_option_global_source_stock_3` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Stock Supplier 3',
  `source_image_url` text COMMENT 'Image URL (scraped products)',
  `category_string` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Category Destination',
  `product_measures` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `product_weight` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `package_height` decimal(6,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `package_length` decimal(6,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `package_width` decimal(6,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `package_weight` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `color` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Main color of product',
  `main_material` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Material of the product',
  `product_type` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Type',
  `designer` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Designer',
  `complementary_products` varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'SKUs of products which might be perfect additions',
  `short_description` text COMMENT 'Key features as bullet points',
  `package_content` text,
  `manufacturer_txt` text COMMENT 'Manufacturer Text',
  `care_label` text COMMENT 'Special care instructions',
  `product_warranty` text COMMENT 'Product warranty',
  `product_warranty_en` text,
  `auk_salesrank` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `capacity_ml` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `source_contract_no_one` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `source_contract_no_two` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `source_contract_no_three` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fk_catalog_attribute_option_global_new_to_market` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `installment_eligible` tinyint(1) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `meta_title` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `meta_description` text,
  `rich_tag_snippet` text,
  `product_owner` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `caching_hash` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `complementary_product_list` text,
  `substitute_product_list` text,
  `product_class` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `noindex` tinyint(1) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `required_serial` tinyint(1) unsigned DEFAULT '0',
  `is_returnable` tinyint(1) unsigned DEFAULT '1',
  `keywords` text,
  `product_invisible` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `warranty_list` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `manufacturing_bar_code_required` tinyint(1) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `genuine_product` tinyint(1) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `cod_not_available` tinyint(1) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `promotion_texts` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `marketplace_parent_sku` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `marketplace_children_skus` text,
  `marketplace_manual_overridden_list` text,
  `sku_payment_blacklist` text,
  `original_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `video` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `disable_automated_seo_text` tinyint(1) unsigned DEFAULT '0',
  `package_dimension_mandatory` tinyint(1) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `fk_catalog_attribute_option_global_product_visibility` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `disable_notify_me` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `force_use_sold_fulfilled_by` tinyint(1) unsigned DEFAULT '0',
  `display_out_of_stock_even_still_available` tinyint(1) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `disable_rich_relevance` tinyint(1) unsigned DEFAULT '0',
  `published_time` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `flash_sale_status` varchar(255) DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'The flashsale status',
  `flash_sale_registration_start_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'The date when registration for flash sales starts',
  `flash_sale_registration_end_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'The date when registration for flash sales ends',
  `flash_sale_start_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'The date when flash sales starts',
  `flash_sale_end_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'The date when flash sales ends',
  `flash_sale_url` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'The flashsale url',
  `shipping_section_details_txt` text,
  `buyer_protection_details_txt` text,
  `name_en` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `description_en` text,
  `fk_catalog_attribute_option_global_return_policies` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT '2',
  `added_group_time` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `fk_catalog_attribute_option_global_bullet_point_options` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `sku` (`sku`),
  KEY `fk_catalog_attribute_set` (`fk_catalog_attribute_set`),
  KEY `fk_catalog_brand` (`fk_catalog_brand`),
  KEY `fk_catalog_config_group` (`fk_catalog_config_group`),
  KEY `fk_catalog_import` (`fk_catalog_import`),
  KEY `pet_approved` (`pet_approved`),
  KEY `name` (`name`),
  KEY `created_at` (`created_at`),
  KEY `updated_at` (`updated_at`),
  KEY `activated_at` (`activated_at`),
  KEY `fk_catalog_attribute_option_global_season` (`fk_catalog_attribute_option_global_season`),
  KEY `fk_catalog_attribute_option_global_gender` (`fk_catalog_attribute_option_global_gender`),
  KEY `fk_catalog_attribute_option_global_source_stock_1` (`fk_catalog_attribute_option_global_source_stock_1`),
  KEY `fk_catalog_attribute_option_global_source_stock_2` (`fk_catalog_attribute_option_global_source_stock_2`),
  KEY `fk_catalog_attribute_option_global_source_stock_3` (`fk_catalog_attribute_option_global_source_stock_3`),
  KEY `fk_catalog_attribute_option_global_supplier_type` (`fk_catalog_attribute_option_global_supplier_type`),
  KEY `fk_catalog_attribute_option_global_new_to_market` (`fk_catalog_attribute_option_global_new_to_market`),
  KEY `status` (`status`),
  KEY `fk_catalog_attribute_option_global_production_country` (`fk_catalog_attribute_option_global_production_country`),
  KEY `primary_category_to_catalog_category` (`primary_category`),
  KEY `catalog_config_supplier_fk` (`product_owner`),
  KEY `marketplace_parent_sku` (`marketplace_parent_sku`),
  KEY `fk_catalog_attribute_option_global_product_visibility` (`fk_catalog_attribute_option_global_product_visibility`),
  KEY `fk_catalog_attribute_option_global_return_policies` (`fk_catalog_attribute_option_global_return_policies`),
  KEY `fk_catalog_attribute_option_global_bullet_point_options` (`fk_catalog_attribute_option_global_bullet_point_options`),
  CONSTRAINT `catalog_config_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`fk_catalog_attribute_set`) REFERENCES `catalog_attribute_set` (`id_catalog_attribute_set`),
  CONSTRAINT `catalog_config_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`fk_catalog_brand`) REFERENCES `catalog_brand` (`id_catalog_brand`),
  CONSTRAINT `catalog_config_ibfk_4` FOREIGN KEY (`fk_catalog_config_group`) REFERENCES `catalog_config_group` (`id_catalog_config_group`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `catalog_config_ibfk_5` FOREIGN KEY (`fk_catalog_import`) REFERENCES `catalog_import` (`id_catalog_import`),
  CONSTRAINT `catalog_config_supplier_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`product_owner`) REFERENCES `supplier` (`id_supplier`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_catalog_attribute_option_global_bullet_point_options` FOREIGN KEY (`fk_catalog_attribute_option_global_bullet_point_options`) REFERENCES `catalog_attribute_option_global_bullet_point_options` (`id_catalog_attribute_option_global_bullet_point_options`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_catalog_attribute_option_global_gender` FOREIGN KEY (`fk_catalog_attribute_option_global_gender`) REFERENCES `catalog_attribute_option_global_gender` (`id_catalog_attribute_option_global_gender`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_catalog_attribute_option_global_new_to_market` FOREIGN KEY (`fk_catalog_attribute_option_global_new_to_market`) REFERENCES `catalog_attribute_option_global_new_to_market` (`id_catalog_attribute_option_global_new_to_market`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_catalog_attribute_option_global_product_visibility` FOREIGN KEY (`fk_catalog_attribute_option_global_product_visibility`) REFERENCES `catalog_attribute_option_global_product_visibility` (`id_catalog_attribute_option_global_product_visibility`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_catalog_attribute_option_global_production_country` FOREIGN KEY (`fk_catalog_attribute_option_global_production_country`) REFERENCES `catalog_attribute_option_global_production_country` (`id_catalog_attribute_option_global_production_country`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_catalog_attribute_option_global_return_policies_constraint` FOREIGN KEY (`fk_catalog_attribute_option_global_return_policies`) REFERENCES `catalog_attribute_option_global_return_policies` (`id_catalog_attribute_option_global_return_policies`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_catalog_attribute_option_global_season` FOREIGN KEY (`fk_catalog_attribute_option_global_season`) REFERENCES `catalog_attribute_option_global_season` (`id_catalog_attribute_option_global_season`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_catalog_attribute_option_global_source_stock_1` FOREIGN KEY (`fk_catalog_attribute_option_global_source_stock_1`) REFERENCES `catalog_attribute_option_global_source_stock_1` (`id_catalog_attribute_option_global_source_stock_1`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_catalog_attribute_option_global_source_stock_2` FOREIGN KEY (`fk_catalog_attribute_option_global_source_stock_2`) REFERENCES `catalog_attribute_option_global_source_stock_2` (`id_catalog_attribute_option_global_source_stock_2`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_catalog_attribute_option_global_source_stock_3` FOREIGN KEY (`fk_catalog_attribute_option_global_source_stock_3`) REFERENCES `catalog_attribute_option_global_source_stock_3` (`id_catalog_attribute_option_global_source_stock_3`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_catalog_attribute_option_global_supplier_type` FOREIGN KEY (`fk_catalog_attribute_option_global_supplier_type`) REFERENCES `catalog_attribute_option_global_supplier_type` (`id_catalog_attribute_option_global_supplier_type`),
  CONSTRAINT `primary_category_to_catalog_category` FOREIGN KEY (`primary_category`) REFERENCES `catalog_category` (`id_catalog_category`) ON DELETE SET NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=987565 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: `select * from table_name where id = 300866` shows what?

Comment: Shows a result : mysql> select * from table_name where id = 300866\G 
id_catalog_config: 300866 sku: 
                                                 status: active
                                 status_supplier_config: active

Comment: odd. what about `show keys from table_name`

Comment: this is not usual error we get while adding column..something different going wrong here

Comment: Do you have a trigger?

Comment: try this `create table new_table like table_name`, then add the column on the new table, then insert the data from the old table to the new

Comment: @Pala - do you want me to give all the result for that syntax? mysql> show keys from dbname.tablename\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
        Table: tablename
   Non_unique: 0
     Key_name: PRIMARY
 Seq_in_index: 1
  Column_name: id
    Collation: A
  Cardinality: 333374
     Sub_part: NULL
       Packed: NULL
         Null: 
   Index_type: BTREE
      Comment: 
Index_comment:

Comment: @Nagendara - this is the first time that I encountered this error :(

Comment: you should put the info in your question, not the comments

Comment: the other info you should put is the `show create table table_name` output

Comment: Please check above ^

Comment: i think that table scared everyone off

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`create table new_table like table_name;`
`alter table new_table add new_column tinyint(1) unsigned default 1;`
`insert into new_table select * from table_name;`

If that works, just get rid of `table_name` and rename `new_table` to `table_name`. If it doesn't work.. post the errors

also, please let us know the output of `show triggers`